# Get Students Free Time (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL Server db where I have a `Students` table with columns `ID`, `Name`, `Surname` etc. I also have a second `Meetings` table with columns `StartTime`, `EndTime` and `StudentId` as foreign key to students.

Now I want to write a query to get students who have a specified amount of free time between any two meetings. Later I will need to translate this to a LINQ query.

How can I write this query?

Comment: This is exactly why I don't like ORMs. If they just wanted to do mapping from SQL results to entities, that would be fine, but they typically go beyond and try to write the SQL for you, too, and this is where they fail. In the end, they don't save you from having to know and write complicated SQL. Ultimately they add to the mental burden of the programmer, because you must know both the ORM syntax and the SQL syntax.

Comment: ... to counter-argument my own post, this is less true on larger teams. ORMs offer a lower barrier to entry for the basic stuff, so ORM use allows you hire more junior developers, which helps the team be more tolerant to turnover. You can then assign the more complicated queries to the more experienced developers.

Comment: _If they just wanted to do mapping from SQL results to entities_ Exactly the reason I choose Dapper everytime.

Comment: Is it allowed that the free time be between the start of day and the start of the first meeting, or the end of the last meeting and the end of day, or must it always be between meetings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rough suggestion:

- Create a view (or [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) that uses [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to number each student's `Meeting` rows sequentially.
- Join that view to itself on `b.RowNum = a.RowNum + 1 and a.StudentID = b.StudentID`. This gives you one row per free block, where `a` is an arbitrary meeting and `b` is the meeting that follows it for that student. Select `b.StartTime - a.EndTime` to find the duration of each free block. You can expose this joined query as its own view, called `FreeBlocks`.
- It should then be simple to query the `FreeBlocks` view for students with a free block of any desired duration. You can query the view from either SQL or LINQ.